# I cannot fast travel to any of my DLC downloaded from the season pass

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2

I have downloaded it several times in the Borderlands 2 menu, but each time it has not worked. I have tried deleting the DLC from my flash drive and redownloading it but that hasn't worked either. Could it be because I am downloading it onto a flash drive? 
Also I've checked the downloadable content menu and it says I have them installed.

Comment: We're going to need a little context here. Where are your BL2 main files located? Is it also on the flashstick, or is it on the main computer? As far as I know, DLC should be in the same folder where your main BL2 files.

Comment: The flash drive is in my xbox. I use it for all of my DLC so I can have extra space on my hard drive. All of the other DLCs work just fine, though.